# Would DateTimeField() work if I have time in this format 1/7/11 9:15 ? If not what would?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am importing data from a JSON file and it has the date in the following format  `1/7/11 9:15`

What would be the best variable type/format to define in order to accept this date as it is?  If not what would be the most efficient way to accomplish this task?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would it not work?

Comment: I thought DateTimeFiled had a different format...

Comment: It doesn't have any format, it stores DateTimes. You need to convert from string into datetime, no matter what format the original is in.

Comment: so for sorting and all that it will still work? interesting...  I thought the format was important for it to appropriately recognize year vs month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "What would be the best variable type/format to define in order to accept this date as it is?"

The [DateTimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield).

> "If not what would be the most efficient way to accomplish this task?"

You should use [the `datetime.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) method from Python's builtin `datetime` library:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import json

>>> json_datetime = "1/7/11 9:15"  # still encoded as JSON
>>> py_datetime = json.loads(json_datetime)  # now decoded to a Python string
>>> datetime.strptime(py_datetime, "%m/%d/%y %I:%M")  # coerced into a datetime object
datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 7, 9, 15)

# Now you can save this object to a DateTimeField in a Django model.
```

Comment: awesome. thanks so much! Also, what would happen if the format was 7/1/11 as in a language like Spanish. Would that arrangement be problematic and how could someone fix this to have datetime correctly recognize that 7 is the day and not the month in this context?

Comment: You'd probably have to know what format the date is coming in.  For the `7/1/11` example, you would need to switch the `%m` and the `%d` in the second argument passed to `strptime()`.  You can learn more about how that works in the "[strftime() and strptime() Behavior](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)" section of the docs.  You might also be interested in [magicdate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/magicdate/0.1.3), a Python package that coerces many common date formats into `datetime` objects.  (It won't, however, solve the flipped month issue)

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield, it says that django uses the python datetime library which is docomented at http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html.

Here is a working example (with many debug prints and step-by-step instructions:

```
from datetime import datetime

json_datetime = "1/7/11 9:15"
json_date, json_time = json_datetime.split(" ")
print json_date
print json_time
day, month, year = map(int, json_date.split("/")) #maps each string in stringlist resulting from split to an int
year = 2000 + year #be ceareful here! 2 digits for a year may cause trouble!!! (could be 1911 as well)
hours, minutes = map(int, json_time.split(":"))
print day
print month
print year
my_datetime = datetime(year, month, day, hours, minutes)
print my_datetime

#Generate a json date:
new_json_style = "{0}/{1}/{2} {3}:{4}".format(my_datetime.day, my_datetime.month, my_datetime.year, my_datetime.hour, my_datetime.minute)
print new_json_style
```